# Shortest line between boundary points that passes through the centroid of a shape

Tags: matlab, geometry, line, shapes, min

[lesion image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqwte.jpg)

I have an irregularly shaped object in which I have to find the greatest and smallest diameter.

To find the greatest diameter, I extracted the boundary points and found the distances between all the points. I took the maximum distance amongst those distances which gave me my greatest diameter.

```
boundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
numberOfBoundaries = size(boundaries, 1);
for blobIndex = 1 : numberOfBoundaries
    thisBoundary = boundaries{blobIndex};
    x = thisBoundary(:, 2); % x = columns.
    y = thisBoundary(:, 1); % y = rows.

    % Find which two boundary points are farthest from each other.
    maxDistance = -inf;
    for k = 1 : length(x)
        distances = sqrt( (x(k) - x) .^ 2 + (y(k) - y) .^ 2 );
        [thisMaxDistance, indexOfMaxDistance] = max(distances);
        if thisMaxDistance > maxDistance
            maxDistance = thisMaxDistance;
            index1 = k;
            index2 = indexOfMaxDistance;
        end
    end
```

I have attached my image containing the longest diameter.

[image: GREATEST DIAMETER]

I also need a line segment that passes through the centroid connecting the two boundary points whose length is shortest. When I try to find the shortest diameter by modifying the above code, to find `min(distances)`, I am getting an error that says:

> Error using `griddedInterpolant`
>   The coordinates of the input points must be finite values; `Inf` and `NaN` are not permitted.

What do I need to do to find the shortest "diameter" (that is, passing through the centroid) of this object?

Comment: What line gives you that error?

Comment: When I take min(distances), I am getting zero. That is probably why I am getting the error. Is my logic for finding the shortest diameter right?

Comment: When you change the `max` for `min` you look for 2 boundary points that are the closest together. Obviously this will be any point of the boundary and itself, at zero distance.

Comment: If you post the `binaryImage` that you use in the beginning of the code I may be able to help.

Comment: I have edited my question and attached the image. Please guide.

Comment: I read about the minimum feret diameter. Can that be used to find the shortest diameter in this case. My doubt is that, what if the shortest diameter points don't lie on the lesion boundary but on the bounding box.

Comment: I will try to write an answer, but this has a clear solution using PCA (or eigenvalue decomposition). The eigenvector will define the direction of the longest orthogonal paths on your blob.

Comment: Will PCA help me find shortest diameter through centroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible to use a polar image like this:

```
lesion = imread('lesion.jpg');
bw = lesion > 100;
c = regionprops(bw,'Centroid');
c = c.Centroid;
% polar args
t = linspace(0,2*pi,361);
t(end) = [];
r = 0:ceil(sqrt(numel(bw)/4));
[tg,rg] = meshgrid(t,r);
[xg,yg] = pol2cart(tg,rg);
xoff = xg + c(1);
yoff = yg + c(2);
% polar image
pbw = interp2(double(bw),xoff,yoff,'nearest') == 1;
[~,radlen] = min(pbw,[],1);
radlen(radlen == 1) = max(r);
n = numel(radlen);
% add two edges of line to form diameter
diamlen = radlen(1:n/2) + radlen(n/2+1:n);
% find min diameter
[mindiam,tminidx1] = min(diamlen);
tmin = t(tminidx1);
rmin = radlen(tminidx1);
tminidx2 = tminidx1 + n/2;
xx = [xoff(radlen(tminidx1),tminidx1) xoff(radlen(tminidx2),tminidx2)];
yy = [yoff(radlen(tminidx1),tminidx1) yoff(radlen(tminidx2),tminidx2)];
% viz
figure;
subplot(121);
imshow(pbw);
title('polar image');
subplot(122);
imshow(bw);
hold on
plot(c(1),c(2),'or')
plot(xx,yy,'g')
legend('centroid','shortest diameter');
```

and the output is:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much! 
But in bw>100, is 100 a fixed value? What does it mean?

Comment: `bw = lesion > 100` is just my way to create the binary lesion image for this example. it has nothing to do with the suggested algorithm, and you can drop this line and use your own image.

Comment: I had a doubt in the code you have used. what exactly does `radlen(radlen==1)=max(r)` mean?

Comment: Also, how does converting it to polar form initially help? I am trying to understand the algorithm you have used here. Can you please explain how you are finding the shortest diameter? '@user2999345'

Comment: it makes sure that radius lengths which found to be minimal (=1) and are really not, set to maximal. actually the right way to do that is: `[binaryVal,radlen] = min(pbw,[],1);` and then `radlen(binaryVal == 1) = max(r);`.

Comment: converting it to polar when the center of the polar axes is the centroid of the lesion makes an image of the radiis side-by-side, then you check their lengths and add lengths of radiis 180 deg' apart (to get diameters).

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you are trying to say. Could you please explain a bit further.

Comment: look at [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wai_Wong7/publication/233942617/figure/fig3/AS:300072504971268@1448554268989/Figure-4-Resultant-image-from-Figure-2-after-the-log-polar-transformation.png).

it lets you arrange the pixels along each angle as a column and then it is easier to analyse polar information (like shortest diameter)